# The coolant leaks on the ISS and associated spaceships: are they still mysterious?

Tags: iss, leak, nauka

Are the real reasons now known that  caused the leaks in the Soyouz, Progress and heater exchange devices on the Nauka  module causing the loss of that special liquid and giving a lot of troubles to the ISS crews? Thanks.

Comment: Does this specifically refer to coolant leaks (in which case I suggest an appropriate edit to the subject line), or does it include the occasional randomly-drilled hole?

Comment: @ Mark Yes, it refers to the coolant leaks. I updated.

Answer (score 4):

According to Roscosmos (and supported by NASA) the recent 2023 coolant leak issues on Progress and Nauka were the result of micrometeorite impacts damaging the systems.

Quote from [this article](https://spacenews.com/russian-iss-module-experiences-coolant-leak/), in relation to what caused the damage:

> “The NASA team has also looked at it, independent of the Russian team, and we also cannot find anything, based on the information we’ve been given by our Russian colleagues, of anything other than some type of external force or debris or something else like that,” said Joel Montalbano, NASA ISS program manager, at a July briefing.

Comment: The Soyuz as well. https://www.reuters.com/science/russian-module-international-space-station-springs-coolant-leak-2023-10-09/ Conspicuously absent from all these explanations is why, after decades of trouble-free use, Russian coolant systems developed a vulnerability to impact damage all of a sudden.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, the whole thing is fishy. Montalbanos' quote has enough weasel words ("based on the information we've been given") that it doesn't feel good, and Roscosmos becomes more non-credible by the month. I think NASA has been instructed from on high / decided internally to not criticize Roscosmos in any way despite all the recent goofs for "stability" reasons. The leaks, EVA nonsense, the drilled hole, the iss-suplex maneuver, are all things they should be called out and held accountable for, but ISS is just in a precarious situation.